# naming the overloaded getter methods : const and non-const

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class A
{
  public:
    B* get_b() const;

    const B* get_b() const;
};
```

This is illegal because the 2 overloaded methods only diff in the return type. But semantically they are exactly what I want: neither function should modify the A object "inside these methods" while the first allows the caller to modify the object "after" calling the method.

I see 2 solutions:
1. Remove const from the first method because even the method itself does not modify the object, it returns a non-const data which could be modified later.

2. Name the methods differently

How do you see?

[UPDATE]
OK, I guess I should just remove the 2nd one. The reasoning is the method should just focuses on itself(the method modifies the object or not) and should not restrict how the client uses the data(if the data can potentially be modified).

Comment: The second version brings nothing compared to the one returning non const B*. Just offer the first one, users are free to store a non const B* in a const B*.

Comment: Why are you offering two function overloads that have different semantics? That is confusing as hell and bound to lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: @Borgleader That should really be an answer, I think.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate, since the user re-asked the question (more clearly) in a separate post and accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you cannot overload a function by return type - that's it. Consider an example:

```
int GetValue();
float GetValue();

// Call it
GetValue(); // Which one?
```

You aren't assigning the return value to any value, or using `GetValue` in any expression, you (reader) cannot figure out which function will be called. Even if you assign:

```
double x = GetValue();
```

And **assuming** that compiler can deduce based on return type, there is still ambiguity - which function to call, since return value of both (`int`, and `float`) can be converted to `double`. In short, the language doesn't allow function overload based on return type, irrespective of `const`, pointer or reference type added to return type.

Comment: The return type isn't part of the function signature, that's all. It doesn't have to do with deducing return types.

Comment: Yes. And I just illustrated why (becuase compiler wont be able to resolve overload ambiguity)

Comment: The answer is just worded confusingly.