# return const and non-const value from getter method

Tags: c++

I asked one question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845249/naming-the-overloaded-getter-methods-const-and-non-const) which did not get desirable response, I am still pondering on the topic, so start this new question, hopefully I can describe my wondering better.

I have a code like this:

```
struct A
{
  P* get_p() const;
};

void dump_p(const A *a)
{
  const P* p = a->get_p();
  ...... dump out p's content for debugging purpose ......
}

void re-format(A *a)
{
   P* p = a->get_p();
   ...... update p's content ......
}
```

You can see dump_p() is really a read-only function, but get_p() returns a free pointer which allows caller to update the data freely. This is nagging to me, I am thinking a solution compiler can help enforcing the semantic check.

This is what I come up:

```
struct A
{
  P* get_p() const;
  const P* get_rdonly_p() const;
};

void dump_p(const A *a)
{
  const P* p = a->get_rdonly_p();
}

void re-format(A *a)
{
   P* p = a->get_p();
}
```

Add this get_rdonly_p() because c++ does not allow overloading method with different return type only.

Am I going nuts? Or what is your solution?

[UPDATE]
Thanks Adrian, that might be the solution. But I am still banging my head against wall - the non-const version get_p() you mentioned does not 100% satisfies me, the function itself does not change any of the struct A, but I do not declare it as const, this is nagging.

Let me hold checking yours as the answer, very likely it is, maybe c++ lacks some construct at language level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it.

```
struct A
{
  P* get_p();
  const P* get_p() const;
};
```

This overloads `get_p` depending on whether the `A` is const or not.  If `A` is const, then a caller that gets direct access to the pointer should not be able to change it.  The non-const version doesn't directly modify the `A`, but it allows the caller to do so via the returned pointer.

This is a common pattern in libraries that have direct accessors.